# JavaScript: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

The following code does not work on Microsoft Edge. What can I do that it works?

Error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The same-source rule prohibits reading
>   the external resource at https:
>   //spp-0006.int.kaufland/sites/topic-0193/Shared%20Documents/Files/XML_MarketList.xml.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'https://spp-0006.int.kaufland/sites/topic-0193/Shared%20Documents/Dateien/XML_Marktliste.xml', false);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? Or is that URL not CORS-enabled at all?

Comment: Only in Edge? Or in other browsers as well? Because CORS is a general security feature. This should happen everywhere, by design.

Comment: Same in Firefox - generally unless website allows cross-origin requests to this resource, you can't do it with regular request, unless it's an opaque request using fetch with mode no-cors.

Comment: Yeah, this won't work on **all browsers** if CORS is implemented. Nothing specifically to do with Edge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089962/javascript-xmlhttprequest-does-not-work-on-ms-edge)

Comment: it works on Internet Explorer

Comment: Because IE is flawed :) It shouldn't work because this is a security measure

Comment: As the error message said, the request missing the CORS header, you could [use the Network tool in F12 developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004(v%3dvs.85)) to check the request/response header. Then, refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to learn more about CORS and add the CORS header.

Answer (score 0):

Your server must return some **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header, where is indicated website addresses for whitch is allowed to get content from server.

This example will allow to get content from server for any website

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This example will allow to get content from server only for your-site.com

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your-site.com
```

And you have to note, this will not make you more secure, but you must do that, if you want to make xhr request from one domain to another.

Comment: I cant do anything on the server. I have written a JavaScript program which is local on my pc and I need access to XML_Marktliste.xml which is located on a server.

Comment: Then forget to use your program in browser. Use `node program.js`

Comment: it is posible in any environment, in which you can ignore cors.